# Is ~/dotdeb.gpg safe to delete?

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, dotdeb

I have a file called `dotdeb.gpg` in my `root` user's home folder. Would removing this file break the system, is it required?

Comment: Who put it there, and why?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Is was there from the beginning, came with my VSP install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely safe to remove.  If you take a look at root's bash history you might see that it was downloaded and imported so the Dotdeb repository could be used.

From the [Dotdeb](https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) website:

```
3. Fetch and install the GnuPG key

wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

If you want to be safe compare the md5sum of the local file to the one on their website to verify that is where it came from.